# Show that $b\sin\left(\arccos\left(\frac{b^{2}+c^{2}-a^{2}}{2bc}\right)\right)=\sqrt {a^{2}-\left(c-\frac{b^{2}+c^{2}-a^{2}}{2c}\right)^{2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Given that a triangle with sides $a$, $b$, and $c$, where $c$ is the longest side. Show that $$b\sin\left(\arccos\left(\frac{b^{2}+c^{2}-a^{2}}{2bc}\right)\right)=\sqrt {a^{2}-\left(c-\frac{b^{2}+c^{2}-a^{2}}{2c}\right)^{2}}$$
Sorry if you think that I don't pay effort myself to show this, but I don't know how to eliminate the trig functions. I tried using $(\cos x)^{2}+(\sin x)^{2}=1$ but seems don't work. Thanks.

Comment: I can smell cosine rule.

Comment: @Rory Daulton Sorry, you just help me to edit it when I just want to edit it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inverse trig functions should be thought of as angles.  If

$$\arccos\left(\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}\right) = \theta, $$

then

$$\cos \theta = \frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}.$$

So there is a right triangle with hypotenuse $2bc$ and adjacent
side $b^2+c^2-a^2.$  With Pythagorean theorem we can compute the 
opposite side to be $\sqrt{4b^2c^2 -(b^2+c^2-a^2)^2}.$  Then

$$b\sin\theta = b\frac{\sqrt{4b^2c^2 -(b^2+c^2-a^2)^2}}{2bc}.$$

If you expand and simplify this expression, and do the same to
the right side of your identity, you'll see they are equal and
your hand will be tired.

Comment: I can derive left hand side from right hand side, but how could you derive it from left hand side to right hand side?

Comment: How you derive left hand side to right hand side?

Comment: It's a page of horrible algebra.  If you can, as you say, "derive left hand side from right hand side", then just to the opposite steps in the opposite order.

Comment: Actually this is the height of a triangle with side a, b, c and c is the longest side, the left hand side is the form solving by cosine rule and the right hand side is the form solved by using simultaneous equations, but I dont know how to show that left hand side equal to right hand side so I asked here....

Comment: And I told you.  My last expression can be manipulated to look like the right side of your identity.  Just multiply everything out and gather like terms in both expressions.

Comment: I didn't mean that you are wrong, just wish to clarify the situation.

Comment: just now just managed to derive from left to right like you said in the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the [cosine rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines), $$\cos(A) = \frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$$

Also we have the identity $\sin^2x+\cos^2 x=1$. So the left hand side becomes:

$$b\sqrt {1-\left(\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}\right)^2}$$

Comment: Actually I hope not to assume knowing cosine rule to show this, because seems the left hand side is it self derived by cosine rule, I hope using just basic trig identity and algebra methods. but your answer let me have idea about this question...